# Unable to add PostGIS to database due to undefined symbol: proj_get_type

Tags: postgis

I am setting up a PostgreSQL10 server with pgRouting on Fedora 30 VM. by running these command as root:

```bsh
dnf install https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/F-30-x86_64/pgdg-fedora-repo-latest.noarch.rpm

dnf install postgresql10

dnf install postgresql10-server

/usr/pgsql-10/bin/postgresql-10-setup initdb
systemctl enable postgresql-10
systemctl start postgresql-10

dnf install https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/pgRouting/2.6.2/2.fc30/x86_64/pgRouting-2.6.2-2.fc30.x86_64.rpm
```

When I trying to add the first extension to the database, it failed:

```sql
create extension postgis;

>ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/pgsql-10/lib/postgis-3.so": /usr/pgsql-10/lib/postgis-3.so: undefined symbol: proj_get_type
SQL state: XX000
```

It seems that it is [postgis libraries linking problems](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4467). However, I did't have any legacy libraries installed prior this, so I starts getting lost here. Attempting to update the packages mentioned (proj, geos) did nothing, removing them via dnf would also remove postgis as dependency.

I am not sure that I had to manually build and install everything one by one or possible to solve it by editing some configure file sitting somewhere unknown. I never tried to Build a RPM Package from Source.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the postgis package. Use

```
yum search postgis
```

to find the appropriate package in the repositeries you have set up already.

The most reliable approach is to add the relevant pgdg repositery, update postgres and then add the packages for postgis and pgrouting. See https://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php  for details and links.